# Installing (and loading) both amdgpu and nvidia drivers on the same machine

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, radeon

I have a motherboard that allows for up to 19 video cards to be installed on it, and currently I have 4 nvidia and 2 amd cards installed. I can get the nvidia cards to run fine, but I cannot get the amdgpu drivers to load, or even tell if they were installed correctly. I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2, 5.4.0-42-generic kernel. Following directions I found on another thread I uninstalled the nvidia drivers, grabbed the Radeon 20.45 installer, and ran it using this command:

`./amdgpu-install --opencl=legacy,pal --headless --no-dkms`

I then rebooted, installed the nvidia drivers again, ran the xorg generation command:

`sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=28 --allow-empty-initial-configuration`

and rebooted again. The motherboard has a utility that shows which pcie slots are in use when you boot up, and they are all showing green (no errors). I can see all of the cards when I run `lspci`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (rev cf)
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (rev cf)
0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER] (rev a1)
0d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660] (rev a1)
0e:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER] (rev a1)
0f:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER] (rev a1)
```

I noticed that nvidia-xconfig did not add the amd cards to xorg.conf, so I manually added them in myself:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 460.73.01

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    Screen      3  "Screen3" RightOf "Screen2"
    Screen      4  "Screen4" RightOf "Screen3"
    Screen      5  "Screen5" RightOf "Screen4"
    Screen      6  "Screen6" RightOf "Screen5"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor3"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor4"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor5"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor6"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 710"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER"
    BusID          "PCI:12:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1660"
    BusID          "PCI:13:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device3"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER"
    BusID          "PCI:14:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device4"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER"
    BusID          "PCI:15:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device5"
    Driver         "amdgpu"
    VendorName     "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
    BoardName      "RX480 4GB"
    BusID          "PCI:8:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device6"
    Driver         "amdgpu"
    VendorName     "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
    BoardName      "RX480 4GB"
    BusID          "PCI:10:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
#    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
#    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
#    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen3"
    Device         "Device3"
    Monitor        "Monitor3"
    DefaultDepth    24
#    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen4"
    Device         "Device4"
    Monitor        "Monitor4"
    DefaultDepth    24
#    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen5"
    Device         "Device5"
    Monitor        "Monitor5"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen6"
    Device         "Device6"
    Monitor        "Monitor6"
EndSection
```

But still when I check `sudo lshw -C video` it says that those displays are "unclaimed":

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: cf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef iomemory:2f0-2ef memory:2f60000000-2f6fffffff memory:2f70000000-2f701fffff ioport:9000(size=256) memory:f7300000-f733ffff memory:f7340000-f735ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       version: cf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef iomemory:2f0-2ef memory:2f40000000-2f4fffffff memory:2f50000000-2f501fffff ioport:8000(size=256) memory:f7200000-f723ffff memory:f7240000-f725ffff
```

I checked and I didn't see any blacklisting of the drivers in modprobe.d, and nomodeset is not on in my startup options. Not sure what else to try.